# using numerical filters to define what print list is used (I assume if filters)

Tags: python, parsing, if-statement, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have some code which parses an xml file obtained from a url, using the following code:

```
pattern4 = re.compile('title=\'Naps posted: (.*) Winners:')
pattern5 = re.compile('Winners: (.*)\'><img src=')

for row in xmlload1['rows']:
    cell = row["cell"]

##### defining the Keys (key is the area from which data is pulled in the XML) for use   in the pattern finding/regex
user_delimiter = cell['username']

##### the use of the float here is to make sure the result of the strike rate calculations returns as a decimal, otherwise python 2 rounds to the nearest integer! 
user_numberofselections = float(re.findall(pattern4, user_delimiter)[0])
user_numberofwinners = float(re.findall(pattern5, user_delimiter)[0])

strikeratecalc1 = user_numberofwinners/user_numberofselections
strikeratecalc2 = strikeratecalc1*100

##### Printing the results of the code at hand

print "number of selections = ",user_numberofselections
print "number of winners = ",user_numberofwinners
print "Strike rate = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"
print ""

getData()
```

What i dont know is if it is possible to filter data and print different print lists. I think I shall have to describe an exampleS of what i would like to achieve:

If strikeratecalc2 => 20% but also <30% print "X Strike rate = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"

If strikeratecalc2 => 30% but also <40% print "Y Strike rate = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"

If strikeratecalc2 => 40% but also <50% AND user_numberofselections >100  print "Z Strike rate = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"

If strikeratecalc2 => 50% AND user_numberofselections >100  print "ZA Strike rate = ",strikeratecalc2,"%"

If anyone is able to offer some solutions to what I presume is probably a simple task, I will be able to reverse engineer the answers for my needs. Please let me know if more information is required. Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a (very hacky) solution:

```
letter = 'X' if (strikeratecalc2 >= 0.20 and strikeratecalc2 < 0.30) else 'Y' if \
 (strikeratecalc2 >=  0.30 and strikeratecalc2 <  0.40) \
 else 'Z' if (strikeratecalc2 >= 0.40 and strikeratecalc2 < \
 0.50 and user_numberofselections > 100) else 'ZA' if \
 (strikeratecalc2 >= 0.50 and user_numberofselections  > 100) \
 else 'Default value here'

print letter, 'Strike rate = ' ,strikeratecalc2, '%'
```

Note: I know it is rather hackish, but it works. And it doesn't take 2000 lines of code.

Comment: This is actually the one I used, I dont need a over technical solution,  using simple if functions suited me perfectly :)

Comment: @AEA: Note: If you omit the `else 'Default value here' `, Python gives a Syntax Error. If you are sure that there is absolutely no need for a default value, you can just use `else None`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the note! I have actually not used the else side of the code. I tried to put in a `else continue;` in order to skip on to the next row of the xml if this criteria was not met, but python didnt like that. :S

Comment: @AEA: You're welcome! Python is pretty picky...oh well! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that runs a list of `(strikerate,numberOfSelections)` through a cascading list of filtering predicates, and appends the data to the respective target list:

```
def splitDataStream(data, xlist, ylist, zlist, zalist, otherlist):

    # a little filter-making function for repetitive filters
    def makefilter(minsr,maxsr,minnumselect):
        if minnumselect is not None:
            return lambda sr,numselect : minsr<=sr<maxsr and numselect>minnumselect
        else:
            return lambda sr,numselect : minsr<=sr<maxsr

    # define list of (destination_list, predicate_filtering_condition) tuples
    cascadingFilters = [
        (xlist, makefilter(20,30,None)),
        (ylist, makefilter(30,40,None)),
        (zlist, makefilter(40,50,100)),
        (zalist, makefilter(50,100,100)),
        ]

    # for each data pair, find destination list based on first matching
    # predicate, and append the data to it; if no match, append to otherlist
    for d in data:
        dest = next((destlist for destlist,pred in cascadingFilters if pred(*d)),
                     otherlist)
        dest.append(d)
```

And now run it:

```
# make some dummy sample data
from random import randint
data = [(randint(0,100), randint(0,500)) for i in range(50)]

# or using your findall returned values
user_numberofselections = map(float, re.findall(pattern4, user_delimiter))
user_numberofwinners = map(float, re.findall(pattern5, user_delimiter))
data = []
for selnum,winnum in zip(user_numberofselections, user_numberofwinners):
    strikeratecalc1 = winnum/selnum
    strikeratecalc2 = strikeratecalc1*100
    data.append((strikeratecalc2, selnum))

xlist = []
ylist = []
zlist = []
zalist = []
otherlist = []
splitDataStream(data, xlist, ylist, zlist, zalist, otherlist)

# list all summary lists
for listname in "xlist ylist zlist zalist otherlist".split():
    listvar = locals()[listname]
    print listname, listvar
```

Prints:

```
xlist [(28, 107), (21, 13), (24, 492)]
ylist [(33, 213), (33, 367), (34, 177), (37, 385), (38, 316), (34, 114)]
zlist [(46, 467), (46, 183), (45, 171)]
zalist [(54, 335), (85, 396), (54, 309), (77, 360), (76, 417), (98, 418), (80, 227), (65, 350), (71, 243), (55, 325), (88, 433)]
otherlist [(0, 400), (47, 8), (2, 326), (10, 122), (16, 355), (16, 52), (72, 10), (17, 199), (7, 41), (17, 58), (8, 243), (10, 342), (65, 85), (42, 21), (9, 391), (97, 44), (17, 420), (16, 172), (57, 4), (59, 97), (62, 94), (62, 60), (18, 148), (9, 207), (7, 343), (1, 390), (47, 60)]
```

Comment: @AEA - sorry if my answer seemed like overdesign, I've reformatted it to clarify which parts were solution vs. demonstration.